# VS2013 Test agent and controller not communicating

Tags: windows, networking, visual-studio, azure

I have a Windows Azure VM running VS2013 Load Test Controller and a second Azure VM running 2013 Load Test Agent.

I have not been able to get the two communicating successfully. I added the hostname and IP of each VM to the other's HOSTS file. I also created a local admin account with the same username and password on both machines. Neither machine is joined to a domain. I have also created endpoints for each VM to port 6901/TCP. I am able to telnet from the agent VM to port 6901 on the controller VM.

When I apply the test agent configuration settings, it fails on "Test agent could not connect to the test controller." In the agent configuration log, I see:

Could not get the status from the test agent. Exception: Failed to connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified.

In the event viewer, I see:

Unable to connect to the controller on 'controllerVM:6901'. The agent can connect to the controller but the controller cannot connect to the agent because of following reason: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 168.62.XX.XX:6910. Make sure that the firewall on the test agent machine is not blocking the connection.

I have been completely unable to work around this issue so far. I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable both UAC and Firewall. I faced with this issue and solution was to disable UAC in registry. It is applicable for Window 8+ hosts, if you are running Test Controller or Test Agent on it.
Refer to this article: [link](http://www.eightforums.com/system-security/2434-disable-uac-completely.html)
You can do it by the following command:
`reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

Chek your antivirus if you have it. May be you should add exclusion rule for it.